# How do bit fields and their alignments work in C programming?

Tags: c, struct, alignment, field, bit

I need your help at understanding how bit fields work in C programming.

I have declared this struct:

```
struct message
{
    unsigned char first_char : 6;
    unsigned char second_char : 6;
    unsigned char third_char : 6;
    unsigned char fourth_char : 6;
    unsigned char fifth_char : 6;
    unsigned char sixth_char : 6;
    unsigned char seventh_char : 6;
    unsigned char eigth_char : 6;
}__packed message;
```

I saved the size of the struct into an integer using sizeof(message).

I thought the value of the size will be 6 since 6 * 8 = 48 bits, which is 6 bytes,
but instead it has the size value of 8 bytes.

Can anyone explain to me why, and how exactly bit fields and their alignments work?

EDIT

i forgot to explain the situation where i use the struct.
lets say i receive packet of 6 bytes in this form:
`void * packet`

i then cast the data like this:

```
message * msg = (message *)packet;
```

now i want to print the value of each member, so although i declared the members as 6 bits, the members use 8 bits which cause to wrong result when printing.
for example i receive the next data:

`00001111 11110000 00110011 00001111 00111100 00011100`

i thought the value of the members will be as shown below:

`first_char = 000011`

`second = 111111`

`third = 000000`

`fourth = 110011`

`fifth = 000011`

`sixth = 110011`

`seventh = 110000`

`eigth = 011100`

but that is not what hapening, i hope i explained it well, if not please tell me.

Comment: You're declaring 8 chars, why would you expect that to be 6 byte long?

Comment: Are you trying to implement [base64 encoding/decoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)?

Comment: i checked google and found nothing. in each of the 8 chars i only use 6 bits, if you count it you get 48 bits and that is 6 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

Bit-fields don't have to run across different underlying elements ("units"), so you're witnessing that each of your fields occupies an entire unsigned char.  The behaviour is implemention-defined, thoug; cf. C11 6.7.2.1/11:

> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
>   structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
>   implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
>   low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
>   addressable storage unit is unspecified.

Additionally, no bit-field may be larger than what would fit into one single unit, by the constraint in 6.7.2.1/4:

> The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant
>   expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the
>   type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted.

Comment: I'd like to give you an extra +1 for the §6.7.2.1 ¶4 quote.  You might expand on that to note that the type were changed to `unsigned long`, you get completely different packing behaviour.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I think `unsigned long` itself is only conditionally supported. The only universally allowed unit types are `_Bool`, `signed int` and `unsigned int` (6.7.2.1/5)... :-(

Comment: Yes; there are a number of constraints like that…I've added demo code to my answer that works with GCC 4.9.0 under fairly stringent compiler warnings and show different results for `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, and `unsigned long` on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: I thought the C standard forbade bit fields from straddling allocation units--a restriction I thought was silly, but was there nonetheless.  Am I misremembering, or did C11 change the rules?

Comment: @supercat: Don't know, I don't have any older versions of the standard around. My guess is that it's always been allowed, though...

Answer (score 3):

Almost everything about bit-fields is implementation defined.  In particular, how bit-fields are packed together is implementation defined.  An implementation need not let bit-fields cross the boundaries of addressable storage units, and it appears that yours does not.

> #### ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> ¶11 An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field.
>   If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a
>   structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains,
>   whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is
>   implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
>   low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the
>   addressable storage unit is unspecified

And that is by no means the end of the 'implementation-defined' features of bit-fields.

*[Please choose the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23458827/15168) by [Kerek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596781/kerrek-sb) rather than this one as it has the crucial information about §6.7.2.1 ¶4 as well.]*

---

#### Example code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if !defined(BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE)
#define BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE char
#endif

int main(void)
{
    typedef struct Message
    {
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE first_char   : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE second_char  : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE third_char   : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE fourth_char  : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE fifth_char   : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE sixth_char   : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE seventh_char : 6;
        unsigned BITFIELD_BASE_TYPE eighth_char  : 6;
    } Message;

    typedef union Bytes_Message
    {
        Message m;
        unsigned char b[sizeof(Message)];
    } Bytes_Message;

    Bytes_Message u;

    printf("Message size: %zu\n", sizeof(Message));

    u.m.first_char   = 0x3F;
    u.m.second_char  = 0x15;
    u.m.third_char   = 0x2A;
    u.m.fourth_char  = 0x11;
    u.m.fifth_char   = 0x00;
    u.m.sixth_char   = 0x23;
    u.m.seventh_char = 0x1C;
    u.m.eighth_char  = 0x3A;

    printf("Bit fields: %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X %.2X\n",
           u.m.first_char,   u.m.second_char, u.m.third_char,
           u.m.fourth_char,  u.m.fifth_char,  u.m.sixth_char,
           u.m.seventh_char, u.m.eighth_char);

    printf("Bytes:     ");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(Message); i++)
        printf(" %.2X", u.b[i]);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample compilations and runs

Testing on Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks with GCC 4.9.0 (64-bit build; `sizeof(int) == 4` and `sizeof(long_ == 8`).  Source code is in `bf.c`; the program created is `bf`.

```
$ gcc -DBITFIELD_BASE_TYPE=char -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror bf.c -o bf
$ ./bf
Message size: 8
Bit fields: 3F 15 2A 11 00 23 1C 3A
Bytes:      3F 15 2A 11 00 23 1C 3A
$ gcc -DBITFIELD_BASE_TYPE=short -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror bf.c -o bf
$ ./bf
Message size: 8
Bit fields: 3F 15 2A 11 00 23 1C 3A
Bytes:      7F 05 6A 04 C0 08 9C 0E
$ gcc -DBITFIELD_BASE_TYPE=int -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror bf.c -o bf
$ ./bf
Message size: 8
Bit fields: 3F 15 2A 11 00 23 1C 3A
Bytes:      7F A5 46 00 23 A7 03 00
$ gcc -DBITFIELD_BASE_TYPE=long -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror bf.c -o bf
$ ./bf
Message size: 8
Bit fields: 3F 15 2A 11 00 23 1C 3A
Bytes:      7F A5 46 C0 C8 E9 00 00
$
```

Note that there are 4 different sets of results for the 4 different type sizes.  Note, too, that a compiler is not required to allow these types.  The standard says (§6.7.2.1 again):

> ¶4 The expression that specifies the width of a bit-field shall be an integer constant
>   expression with a nonnegative value that does not exceed the width of an object of the
>   type that would be specified were the colon and expression omitted.<sup>122)</sup> If the value is
>   zero, the declaration shall have no declarator.
>
> ¶5 A bit-field shall have a type that is a qualified or unqualified version of `_Bool`, `signed
>   int`, `unsigned int`, or some other implementation-defined type.
>
> <sup>122)</sup> While the number of bits in a `_Bool` object is at least `CHAR_BIT`, the width (number of sign and
>   value bits) of a `_Bool` may be just 1 bit.

---

#### Another sub-question

> Can you explain to me why I was wrong with thinking I would get the size of 6? I asked a lot of my friends but they don't know much about bit-fields.

I'm not sure I know all that much about bit-fields.  I've never used them except in answers to questions on Stack Overflow.  They're of no use when writing portable software, and I aim to write portable software — or, at least, software that is not gratuitously non-portable.

I imagine that you assumed a layout of the bits roughly equivalent to this:

```
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|  f1  |  f2  |  f3  |  f4  |  f5  |  f6  |  f7  |  f8  |
+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

It is supposed to represent 48 bits in 8 groups of 6 bits, laid out contiguously with no spaces or padding.

Now, one reason why that can't happen is the rule from §6.7.2.1 ¶4 that when you use a type `T` for a bit-field, then the width of the bit-field cannot be larger than `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(T)`.  In your code, `T` was `unsigned char`, so bit-fields cannot be larger than 8 bits or else they cross storage unit boundaries.  Of course, yours are only 6 bits, but it means that you can't fit a second bit-field into the storage unit. If `T` is `unsigned short`, then only two 6-bit fields fit into a 16-bit storage unit; if `T` is a 32-bit `int`, then five 6-bit fields can fit; if `T` is a 64-bit `unsigned long`, then 10 6-bit fields can fit.

Another reason is that access to such bit-fields that cross byte boundaries would be moderately inefficient.  For example, given (`Message` as defined in my example code):

```
Message bf = …initialization code…

int nv = 0x2A;
bf.second_char = nv;
```

Suppose that the code treated the values as being stored in a packed byte array with fields overlapping byte boundaries.  Then the code needs to set the bits marked `y` below:

```
             Byte 0             |            Byte 1
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
| x | x | x | x | x | x | y | y | y | y | y | y | z | z | z | z |
+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

This is a pattern of bits.  The `x` bits might correspond to `first_char`; the `z` bits might correspond to part of `third_char`; and the `y` bits to the old value of `second_char`.  So, the assignment has to copy the first 6 bits of Byte 0 and assign 2 bits of the new value to the last two bits:

```
((unsigned char *)&bf)[0] = (((unsigned char *)&bf)[0] & 0xFC) | ((nv >> 4) & 0x03);
((unsigned char *)&bf)[1] = (((unsigned char *)&bf)[1] & 0x0F) | ((nv << 4) & 0xF0);
```

If it is treated as a 16-bit unit, then the code would be equivalent to:

```
((unsigned short *)&bf)[0] = (((unsigned char *)&bf)[0] & 0xFC0F) | ((nv << 4) & 0x03F0);
```

The 32-bit or 64-bit assignments are somewhat similar to the 16-bit version:

```
((unsigned int  *)&bf)[0] = (((unsigned int  *)&bf)[0] & 0xFC0FFFFF) |
                                           ((nv << 20) & 0x03F00000);
((unsigned long *)&bf)[0] = (((unsigned long *)&bf)[0] & 0xFC0FFFFFFFFFFFFF) |
                                           ((nv << 52) & 0x03F0000000000000);
```

This makes a particular set of assumptions about the way the bits are laid out inside the bit-field.  Different assumptions come up with slightly different expressions, but something analogous to this is needed if the bit-field is treated as a contiguous array of bits.

By comparison, with the 6-bits per byte layout actually used, the assignment becomes much simpler:

```
((unsigned char *)&bf)[1] = nv & 0x3F;
```

and it would be legitimate for the compiler to omit the mask operation shown as the values in the padding bits is indeterminate (but the value would have to be an 8-bit assignment).

The amount of code needed to access a bit-field is one reason why most people avoid them.  The fact that different compilers can make different layout assumptions for the same definition means that values cannot be reliably passed between machines of different types.  Usually, an ABI will define the details that Standard C does not, but if one machine is a PowerPC or SPARC and the other is based on Intel, then all bets are off.  It becomes better to do the shifting and masking yourself; at least the cost of the computation is visible.

Comment: i'm not sure i understand, can you explain to me why i was wrong with thinking i would get the size of 6?, i asked a lot of my friends but they dont know much about bit fields.

Comment: Lots of useful information here, but I disagree with the editorial. Bitfields are completely portable (as long as you use a portable base type) and modern compilers optimize them well; the resulting code is more readable particularly for boolean flags implemented as single bits, and it is much more maintainable. The fact that bitfields cannot be trivially serialized in a cross-platform fashion does not make their use non-portable; otherwise, you'd have to avoid any datatype other than char (since endianness varies by platform), especially floating point (you can't rely on IEEE floats)...

Comment: I guess it depends on your definition of portability, then.  Mine includes serialization issues — it seems yours does not.

Comment: ... While you can't use bitfields to describe an x-plat serialization format (which is unfortunate), you can still use them to decrease data size; a typical use is packing several flags (and maybe very small enums) into a `struct` datatype which will be instantiated a very large number of times. Such compression is often premature optimization, of course, but the advantage of using bitfields is that you can do the optimization when you need it without altering any client code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: your definition of portability apparently lets you ignore endanness. That's a very flexible definition of "includes serialization issues" :)

Comment: No; my definition includes using serialization code.  We're going to need to disagree.  I won't recommend bit-fields.  You may write your own answer doing so if you wish.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: So use serialization code to serialize bitfields. It's no more difficult than endianness, and much easier than serializing floats. I don't need to provide an answer; IMO, Kerrek SB's is just fine, as would be yours without the editorializing.