# Have fields in bit fields got contiguous memory location for its elements? Is this behavior compiler independent?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, struct, bit-manipulation

In a bit field in C, are the memory locations of its elements contiguous?
If yes, is this behavior equal for all compilers?

Example:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8_t        in_alarm      :1;
   uint8_t        fault         :1;
   uint8_t        overridden    :1;
   uint8_t        out_of_service:1;
}StatusFlag_t;
```

Will the fields in_alarm, fault etc have contiguous memory locations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost every aspect of bit-field handling is compiler dependent according to the C standard.  The chances are that the 4 bits in your structure will be contiguous in a single byte, but it is not guaranteed whether they'll be the most-significant or least-significant 4 bits.  If there were more than 8 bits, then the values would cross more than one storage unit (because the base type is `uint8_t`; note that the C standard does not require a compiler to support the use of `uint8_t` as the type of a bit-field).  Note that bit-field members usually do not have different addresses; you can't take the address of a bit-field element.

There is no guarantee that different compilers will behave the same across different platforms.  There is typically an ABI (application binary interface) which defines the behaviour for a particular O/S, and the compiler will adhere to the ABI for the platform on which it is running.  But the C standard does not mandate this behaviour.

For relevant quotes from the standard, see (amongst other possibilities) [How do bit-fields and their alignments work in C programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23458733/how-do-bit-fields-and-their-alignments-work-in-c-programming/23458891#23458891)

Answer (score 0):

Well, they don't have memory locations, because they are less than byte. You can't take pointer to a bitfield.

The fields should be packed together as much as possible.

Formally the exact bit allocation is implementation defined. It may differ between compilers.

In practice the 3 main compilers, Gcc, CLang and VisualC++, do the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

The Bits are actually at a only one memory location. One location corresponds to 8 bits.
The order can be compiler dependent i.e. first bit at structure element(in_alarm in your case) should be at MSB or LSB position.(At least my compiler have an option to set that.)

Edit:
As the answer is downvoted and I am not getting why,I am pasting my compiler settingd snapshot to explain what I am trying to convey:

[image]